# Deferrable unique index in postgres

Tags: postgresql, index, transaction, unique-constraint

Looking into [postgres documentation for alter table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-altertable.html), it seems regular constrains can be marked as `DEFERRABLE` (more concretely, `INITIALLY DEFERRED`, which is what I'm interested in).

Indexes can also be associated with a constraint, as long as:

> The index cannot have expression columns nor be a partial index

Which leads me to believe there is currently no way to have a unique index with conditions, like:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_booking
  ON public.booking
  USING btree
  (check_in, check_out)
  WHERE booking_status = 1;
```

To be `INITIALLY DEFERRED`, meaning, that the uniqueness 'constraint' will only be verified on the end of the transaction (if `SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;` is used).

Is my assumption correct, and if so, is there any way to achieve the intended behaviour?

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A index cannot be deferred - doesn't matter if it is `UNIQUE` or not, partial or not, only a `UNIQUE` constraint. Other types of constraints (`FOREIGN KEY`, `PRIMARY KEY`, `EXCLUDE`) are also deferrable - but not `CHECK` constraints.

So the unique partial index (and the implicit constraint it implements) will be checked at every statement (and in fact after every row insert/update in current implementation), not at the end of transaction.

---

What you could do, if you want to implement this constraint as deferrable, is to add one more table in the design. Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE public.booking_status
  ( booking_id int NOT NULL,               -- same types
    check_in timestamp NOT NULL,           -- as in  
    check_out timestamp NOT NULL,          -- booking
    CONSTRAINT unique_booking
        UNIQUE (check_in, check_out)
        DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    CONSTRAINT unique_booking_fk
        FOREIGN KEY (booking_id, check_in, check_out)
        REFERENCES public.booking (booking_id, check_in, check_out)
        DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
  ) ;
```

With this design and assuming that `booking_status` has only 2 possible options (0 and 1), you could remove it entirely from `booking` (if there is a row at `booking_status`, it's 1, if not is 0).

---

Another method would be to (ab)use an `EXCLUDE` constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE booking
    ADD CONSTRAINT unique_booking
        EXCLUDE 
          ( check_in  WITH =, 
            check_out WITH =, 
            (CASE WHEN booking_status = 1 THEN TRUE END) WITH =
          ) 
        DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED ;
```

Tested at **[dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=922ee5331ac108d6fb9780fef86b1132)**.

What the above does:

- The `CASE` expression becomes `NULL` when `booking_status` is null or different than 1. We could write `(CASE WHEN booking_status = 1 THEN TRUE END)` as `(booking_status = 1 OR NULL)` if that makes it any more clear.
- Unique and exclude constraints accept rows where one or more of the expressions is NULL. So it acts as a filtered index with `WHERE booking_status = 1`.
- All the `WITH` operators are `=` so it acts as a `UNIQUE` constraint.
- These two combined make the constraint act as a filtered unique index.
- But it's a constraint and `EXCLUDE` constraints can be deferred.

---

An improvement of the above method (thnx to [Denis Ryzhkov](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/194124/denis-ryzhkov)) is to use a partial (filtered) EXCLUDE constraint. Uses less space (same way as a partial index) and is deferrable:

```
ALTER TABLE booking
    ADD CONSTRAINT unique_booking
        EXCLUDE 
          ( check_in  WITH =, 
            check_out WITH =
          ) 
        WHERE (booking_status = 1)
        DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED ;
```

Tested at **[dbfiddle-2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=e20d67d1aa2f7671ee97d28aec0296d5)**.

Comment: +1 for the EXCLUDE version, was what I needed. Here is another example showing the capabilities of EXCLUDE:
https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/postgresql-exclude-beyond-unique/

Comment: `(CASE WHEN booking_status = 1 THEN TRUE END) WITH =)` should be replaced with `) WHERE (booking_status = 1)` because "Exclusion constraints are implemented using an index", and this partial index with `WHERE` will be smaller and faster - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html

Comment: @DenisRyzhkov thnx for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

Although the years of this question have passed, I would like to clarify for Spanish speakers, the tests have been done in Postgres:

The following constraint was added to a table of 1337 records, where the kit is the primary key:

```
**Bloque 1**
ALTER TABLE ele_kitscompletos
ADD CONSTRAINT unique_div_nkit
PRIMARY KEY (div_nkit)
```

This creates a default primary key NOT DEFERRED for the table so when trying the next UPDATE we get error:

```
update ele_kitscompletos
set div_nkit = div_nkit + 1;
```

> ERROR:  duplicate key violates uniqueness restriction
>   «unique_div_nkit»

In Postgres, executing an UPDATE for each ROW verifies that the RESTRICTION or CONSTRAINT is met.

---

The CONSTRAINT IMMEDIATE is now created and each statement is executed separately:

```
ALTER TABLE ele_kitscompletos
ADD CONSTRAINT unique_div_nkit
PRIMARY KEY (div_nkit)
DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE

**Bloque 2**
BEGIN;   
UPDATE ele_kitscompletos set div_nkit = div_nkit + 1;
INSERT INTO public.ele_kitscompletos(div_nkit, otro_campo)
VALUES 
  (1338, '888150502');
COMMIT;
```

> Query OK, 0 rows affected (execution time: 0 ms; total time: 0 ms)
>   Query OK, 1328 rows affected (execution time: 858 ms; total time: 858
>   ms) ERROR:  llave duplicada viola restricción de unicidad
>   «unique_div_nkit» DETAIL:  Ya existe la llave (div_nkit)=(1338).

Here SI allows changing the primary key since it executes the entire first complete sentence (1328 rows); but although it is in transaction (BEGIN), the CONSTRAINT is validated immediately upon finishing each sentence without having made COMMIT, therefore generates the error when executing the INSERT. Finally we created the CONSTRAINT DEFERRED do the following:

```
**Bloque 3**
ALTER TABLE public.ele_edivipol
DROP CONSTRAINT unique_div_nkit RESTRICT;   

ALTER TABLE ele_edivipol
ADD CONSTRAINT unique_div_nkit
PRIMARY KEY (div_nkit)
DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

If we execute each statement of ** Block 2 **, each sentence separately, no error is generated to the INSERT since it does not validate but the final COMMIT is executed where it finds an inconsistency.

---

For complete information in English I suggest you check the links:

[Deferrable SQL Constraints in Depth](https://begriffs.com/posts/2017-08-27-deferrable-sql-constraints.html)

[NOT DEFERRABLE versus DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300307/not-deferrable-versus-deferrable-initially-immediate/52899392#52899392)